# Error Exit code: 127 when Launching Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator in Python 2.7 Environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've just updated Anaconda navigator. Trying to launch Jupyter Notebook (version 5.7.10) produced the following error:

```
Exit code: 127
```

I've tried to launch this in a Python 2.7 environment, as I need version control for some older tools that are incompatible with Python 3. The spyder installation on that environment takes a suspiciously long time to set up (it actually doesn't seem to install at all).

I could launch jupyter normally on a Python 3 environment. So it seems like something is wrong with the environment manager.

Has Anaconda seized to support pre Python 3 environments (which for me was the main reason for using it as opposed to Google's Colab, say)?

Thanks.